# Why can't I control the click event of this link with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, click

I know jQuery pretty well. This one is driving me nuts because it's SO simple.

I have this in the `<head>`:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_social").click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and in the body I have a series of links:

```
<a class="delete_social" href="save_page.php?delete_social=true">Delete</a>
```

But EVERY time I click those links, it takes me right ot that PHP page. Why isn't jQuery intercepting the click? Any theories?

PS I've tried adding a simple alert() event to the click() function, with no change, and I've tried using "a.delete_social" in the jQuery $() call. Neither worked.

Comment: What do the errors in your error console say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these links are loaded in dynamically, you'll need to use `$.live()` to control them:

```
$(".delete_social").live("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // do stuff
});
```

`$.live()` causes dynamically-added elements to adhere to previously-declared rules.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to prevent the URL from loading:

```
$(".delete_social").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Also, you should be getting an `alert` and other code to run inside the click handler. If it's not, then something else on the page is causing something weird to occur.

Comment: Thanks, yeah. My goal is to run an ajax $.get() in that space, to intercept the URL from the link and run it with $.get() instead. But the ajax never ran, it just went to the URL, so I stripped out the JS and tested with just return false. It's so strange.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of questions I'd ask while debugging:

- Are you sure the click event is being attached to the anchors?

  - Try moving your script take to the bottom of the page and attaching the click events without using the `ready` function.
- Is `$(".delete_social").length` greater than `0`?
- Are there any JavaScript errors when I load the page?
- Is jQuery loading correctly?

  - Does `$.fn.jquery` return the current version of jquery you're using?
- Consider using [`event.preventDefault();`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_social").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the rest of your javascript. `return false;` or `.preventDefault();` should do the trick. If they're not working, it usually means there's an error somewhere else in your js, and your browser never gets to that line of code.